# Tournament with directed edges

Tags: graph

Prove that one can construct a finite tournament G with at least 101 vertices such that: for any subset S of 100 vertices of G, there is some vertex v for which all 100 vertices s ∈ S have a directed edge v → s.

it's suggested to use Globle method